# Compiling with Cython and "next"

Tags: python, c, visual-studio, cython

Any time I use 'next' in my code, I'm thrown this error via VS. It does not seem to matter where or how it's used. The code works fine in Python.
While I can write around using 'next', is there anything I can do to fix this more intelligently?

```
error C2065: '__Pyx_PyIter_Next2': undeclared identifier
```

Example code (edit):

```
rand = None
for i in range(10):
    if rand == None:
        next
```

Comment: You'd need to show some example code to be sure, but this looks like a Cython bug (I think Cython should generate this function itself). If that's the case you should report it to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues

Comment: I'll head there, added a very basic example.

Comment: It looks like you have it fixed but: do you mean `cont` (to start the next iteration of a loop) rather than `next` (a builtin function that you call with an iterator)?

Comment: Correct, the example above is wrong but it still produced the error as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Update to latest beta (0.29b1) from 0.28.5 stable resolved the issue.